# In snowflake , how to convert one date format to another format. From YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MON-DD

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-format, data-conversion, to-date

I have table ABC in which I have column Z of datatype Date. The format of the data is YYYYMMDD. Now I am looking to convert the above format to YYYY-MON-DD format. Can someone help?

Comment: If column z is defined as a date in SF, it should not have format YYYYMMDD.  Is it defined as a varchar?

Comment: Column Z is defined as Number(38,0).  One another question : what would be the format if the column is defined as date?

Comment: Snowflake has a couple of parameters that determine what format you see or what format Snowflake expect. DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT and DATE_INPUT_FORMAT.  The parameter have nothing to do with how the date is stored internally.

Comment: What is the difference between To_char(to_date(To_char(z),'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MON-DD). and. to_date(z,'YYYY-MON-DD'). The first logic works perfectly whereas the second one doesn't work. Why is this. The underlying column Z is of date data type and the preference is set to YYYYMMDD.

Comment: If z is defined as number, you will get an error when you try to_date(z,'YYYY-MON-DD').

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_char

```
TO_CHAR(Z,'YYYY-MON-DD')
```

Comment: I tried this.. but that doesn't work  . I tried the following and it worked. I am not sure what is the difference.   To_char(to_date(To_char(z),'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MON-DD).

Comment: what is the datatype for z in the table ? Can you do a get_ddl to find that out

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the purpose of the reformatting is, you can either explicitly cast it to a VARCHAR/CHAR and define the format, or you can change your display format to however you'd like to see all dates:

```
ALTER SESSION SET DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MON-DD';
```

It's important to understand that if the data is in a DATE field, then it is stored as a date, and the format of the date is dependent on your viewing preferences, not how it is stored.

Comment: What is the difference between To_char(to_date(To_char(z),'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MON-DD).   and.  to_date(z,'YYYY-MON-DD'). The first logic works perfectly whereas the second one doesn't work. Why is this. The underlying column Z is of date data type and the preference is set to YYYYMMDD.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the column z is actually a date data type.  Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of the date field is stored as a number, you have to convert it to date.

ALTER SESSION SET DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MON-DD';

select to_date(to_char( z ), 'YYYYMMDD');

Answer (score 0):

(adding this answer to summarize and resolve the question - since the clues and answers are scattered through comments)

- The question stated that column `Z` is of type `DATE`, but it really seems to be a `NUMBER`.
- Then before parsing a number like `20201017` to a date, first you need to transform it to a `STRING`.
- Once the original number is parsed to a date, it can be represented as a new string formatted as desired.

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 20201017 AS z
)

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(z), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MON-DD')
FROM data;

# 2020-Oct-17
```